# Filter specific API using Tshark

Tags: wireshark, packet-capture, tshark

I run

```
tshark -i eth0 -f "port 80" -w example.pcap
```

to capture the HTTP traffic. And then I run `tshark -r example.pcap -Y xml.tag` to filter the xml. Is this the correct way of filtering the API (SOAP/REST)? Are there any other ways of doing it?

Comment: Hi again Chxk. You should [add more things](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58333838/edit) to your question to make it easier to help you: 1) What do you expect to see? What aren't you seeing? 2) What do you mean by "filter specific API"? Do you have an example? 3) With a filter of "port 80 or port 443", you are capturing http AND https traffic, but you say you are only trying to capture HTTP traffic? 4) Can you give us more background/context on your overall goal?

Comment: @RossJacobs already edited the question and thank you for your comment :D

Comment: 1, 2, and 4 aren't really addressed - please explain the problem (and what you've tried) from the top as if you were talking to a colleague who might not be familiar with your work specifically. It's hard to parse your question in its 39 words.